# C# & PHP - Calling a method to return a value

Tags: c#, php

I have a PHP hashing method that I need to call from my C# program to check a password with my database. Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php
function generateHash($text, $salt = null)
{
    if ($salt === null)
    {
        $salt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 25);
    }
    else
    {
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, 25);
    }
    return $salt.sha1($salt.$text);
}
?>
```

I am trying to set the var $text as something from C# and use a webclient to get the returned value. Here is the C# code:

```
WebClient c = new WebClient();

string r = c.DownloadString("http://www.example.com/hash.php?text=" + pass);
return r;
```

I am new to PHP and dont really know how to fix this. I searched on the internet and found nothing.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your PHP code, you can access the `GET` parameters using the `$_GET` super-global array, like so:

```
if (isset($_GET['text'] && !empty($text)) 
{
    echo generateHash($text);
} 
else 
{
    echo 'Sorry, invalid request.';
}
```

Whenever a client sends a `GET` request to this PHP script with the `text` parameter, the above code will generate a hash and return it. The returned hash can then be used in your C# code (I don't know C#, so I'm not going to show you how).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function generateHash($text, $salt = null)
{
    if ($salt === null)
    {
        $salt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 25);
    }
    else
    {
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, 25);
    }

    return $salt . sha1($salt . $text);
}

$text = $_GET["text"];
echo generateHash($text);
?>
```